# Writing multiple if tags that compare two variables

Tags: c#, number-guessing-game

I am a beginner in C# coding, and I was trying to compare two `int` variables:

> ```
> void CompareNumber() {
>     int oneNumber;
>     int secondNumber;
>
>     if (oneNumber > secondNumber)
>         {
>         DoSomething();
>         }
>
>     else if (oneNumber < secondnumber)
>         {
>         DoSomethingElse();
>         }
>
>     else if (oneNumber == secondnumber)
>          {
>          DoSomethingDifferent();
>          }
> }
> ```

While this does work, it looks kinda messy, especially because I compare variables in this manner many times. Is there a more concise way of doing this, making it look neater? (Except for omitting the curly brackets)

Here is my actual code for a simple game that thinks of a number, and you need to guess what it said:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GuessName
    {
    class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {
            int previousNumber = 0;
            AskNumber(previousNumber);
            }

        static void AskNumber(int previousNumber)
            {
            Console.Clear();

            int numberTyped;
            int randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 11);

            while (previousNumber == randomNumber)
                randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 11);

            Console.WriteLine("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 10. What do you think it is?");


            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberTyped) == true)
                CheckNumber(numberTyped, randomNumber);
            else
                InvalidNumber();
            }

        static void CheckNumber(int numberTyped, int randomNumber)
            {
            if (numberTyped < 0 || numberTyped > 10)
                {
                InvalidNumber();
                }
            else if (numberTyped > randomNumber)
                {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but your number is bigger than what I thought");
                Console.WriteLine("Try again, just type what you think:");
                }
            else if (numberTyped < randomNumber)
                {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but your number is smaller than what I thought");
                Console.WriteLine("Try again, just type what you think:");
                }
            else
                {
                Console.Clear();
                WonGame(randomNumber);
                }
            if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberTyped) == true)
                CheckNumber(numberTyped, randomNumber);
            else
                InvalidNumber();
            }

        static void WonGame(int randomNumber)
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Great job, You did it!");
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to try again? (y) or would you like to quit? (n)");

            string wantToPlay = Console.ReadLine();
            if (wantToPlay == "y")
                AskNumber(randomNumber);
            else
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

        static void InvalidNumber()
            {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("Your number is invalid. Would you like to try again? (y)");
            Console.WriteLine("Or would you like to quit? (n)");

            string wantToPlay = Console.ReadLine();
            if (wantToPlay == "y")
                AskNumber(0);
            else
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Indentation?

At first I thought it was a mere copy/paste error, but the pattern is throughout the code you submitted, so I *have* to mention it: **it's not the braces you indent, it's what the braces encompass!**

> ```
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>         int previousNumber = 0;
>         AskNumber(previousNumber);
>         }
> ```

Should be:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int previousNumber = 0;
        AskNumber(previousNumber);
    }
```

Curly braces define a *scope*. In C#, convention is to place the scope-opening brace *on the next line*, so this:

> ```
> void CompareNumber() {
> ```

Should be:

```
void CompareNumber() 
{
```

Speaking of braces:

> *Is there a more concise way of doing this, making it look neater? (Except for omitting the curly brackets)*

Omitting the curly braces **does not** make code look neater. Proof being this very confusing snippet:

> ```
>         if (wantToPlay == "y")
>             AskNumber(0);
>         else
>             Environment.Exit(0);
>         }
> ```

I had to scan the entire method twice to figure out that the last `}` was in fact closing the scope of the method.

By opposition:

```
        if (wantToPlay == "y")
        {
            AskNumber(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Is brutally in-your-face crystal-clear. Notice the position of the last brace, which closes the method scope. The readability problem stems from the extraneous indentation of scope-delimiting braces - this doesn't suffer the exact same issue:

```
        if (wantToPlay == "y")
            AskNumber(0);
        else
            Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

You should **always** delimit scopes with braces. `if/else` statements denote a scope - that scope wants its braces.

Same with loop constructs:

> ```
>         while (previousNumber == randomNumber)
>             randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 11);
> ```

Should be:

```
        while (previousNumber == randomNumber)
        {
            randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 11);
        }
```

---

#### The Good

You use descriptive naming. This is often understated - descriptive names are your best friend. They reduce bug-proneness of your code all by themselves, and make code easier and more enjoyable to read. Since programming is 80% reading and 20% writing, enjoyable reading means enjoyable programming.

Good job!

---

#### The Bad

The syntax for an `if` condition goes `if ([bool-expression])`, where `[bool-expression]` is any expression that evaluates to `true` or `false`. Can you spot the redundancy here?

> ```
> if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberTyped) == true)
> ```

That's right. `TryParse` returns a `bool` that's a perfectly valid `[bool-expression]` - in fact, anytime you're comparing a Boolean value (or expression) to a Boolean constant *for the sake of getting a Boolean expression*, you are needlessly repeating yourself... redundantly.

Just do this instead:

```
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberTyped))
```

---

Method names should start with a verb. Always. `void InvalidNumber()` is a bad name, because it doesn't say anything about what it actually does - it doesn't return a number, and doesn't intake one either. Without looking at how it's implemented, it's pretty confusing.

---

Console applications exit when the `Main` method executes to its closing brace. I have never used `Environment.Exit(0)` in any application I've written - in fact, this call is like a "red button", a forceful, ugly way to *kill* your application (and throw the body in a container in the back alley) rather than letting it gracefully exit through the front door.

You're going to have to restructure things up in order to make that happen though.

---

`CheckNumber` shouldn't have the `0` and `10` hard-coded like this; there should be constants defined for the lower and upper bounds, and the `AskNumber` method should be using them as well - that way if you ever need to change the `10` to a `100`, there's only 1 place you'll need to change it.

`AskNumber` shouldn't be creating a `new Random()` every time. There should be one single instance of `Random` that the program uses whenever it needs a random number.

There's a lot more to say about this code, I'll let other reviewers chip in ;)

Comment: When you talk about CheckNumber and AskNumber, I am kinda confused there. What do you mean?

Comment: `randomNumber = new Random().Next(1, 11);` appears twice in `AskNumber`, and in `CheckNumber` you have `if (numberTyped < 0 || numberTyped > 10)` - that 0-10 and the 1-11's are the same concept: it's the range of valid values. Make a `private readonly int MinValue = 1` and a `private readonly int MaxValue = 10`. Then you have `randomNumber = new Random().Next(MinValue, MaxValue + 1);` and `if (numberTyped < MinValue || numberTyped > MaxValue)`, and only one character to add to the code if you want to make it 1-100 instead of 1-10.

Comment: The reason newRandom() appears twice is a failsafe to stop the game from accidently picking the same number again. What it does is randomly pick a number, and keeps changing that until it is different from the previous number (hence the while(previousNumber == randomNumber)). The second one, however, makes perfect sense. I will change that right now :) Thanks SO much for your help, my code looks much better now. I still need to figure out how to make it go back to Main() to end properly, instead of using `Environment.Exit(0)`

Comment: @Mat'sMug, why `readonly int` instead of `const int`?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen, Your "failsafe" is going to do the opposite of what you think. If the two `new Random()`s occur close enough together in time, the seed is going to be the same and they'll produce the same series of numbers. If you have a single instance of `Random` as Matt suggests, you'll get a sequence of random numbers as you actually want.

Comment: @BrianS because a `const` value will be burned into its usage locations upon compilation - it doesn't matter in this case, but making would-be-configurable values constants in bigger projects can introduce deployment complications when a dll consumes a const that's defined in another dll - if the values need to change, both dll's would need to be redeployed. Hence, modifying a public const is a breaking change. KISS, don't make configurable values constants to begin with. Again, no impact in this case, but constants should be solely for values unlikely to ever change.

Comment: @BrianS. Ok, that makes sesne. How would I make a failsafe then? To stop the code from making the same number twice.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything wrong with the comparison in the example you showed. To me, at least, it looks like exactly what you need. I think that perhaps your issue with it comes from all of the repetition in your real code.

> ```
>     else if (numberTyped > randomNumber)
>         {
>         Console.Clear();
>         Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but your number is bigger than what I thought");
>         Console.WriteLine("Try again, just type what you think:");
>         }
>     else if (numberTyped < randomNumber)
>         {
>         Console.Clear();
>         Console.WriteLine("Sorry, but your number is smaller than what I thought");
>         Console.WriteLine("Try again, just type what you think:");
>         }
> ```

These two cases are *very* similar. You can extract a method here using `String.Format`.

```
private void WriteWrongGuessMessage(string comparison)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Sorry, but your number is {0} than what I thought.", comparison);
    Console.WriteLine("Try again, just type what you think:");
}
```

And then call it like this.

```
        if (numberTyped < 0 || numberTyped > 10)
        {
            InvalidNumber();
        }
        else if (numberTyped > randomNumber)
        {
            WriteWrongGuessMessage("bigger");
        }
        else if (numberTyped < randomNumber)
        {
            WriteWrongGuessMessage("smaller");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Clear();
            WonGame(randomNumber);
        }
```

---

In general, I think this is pretty good for a novice. Good names, more or less neat (minus the indentation that another answer has already mentioned).

You copy pasted some code though. Don't do that. A wise Mug once said, "Anytime your fingers reach for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> your brain should stop them and write a method instead." I might be paraphrasing a bit, but it's true. Don't repeat yourself. Both `InvalidNumber` and `WonGame` have this code.

> ```
>     string wantToPlay = Console.ReadLine();
>     if (wantToPlay == "y")
>         AskNumber(randomNumber);
>     else
>         Environment.Exit(0);
>     }
> ```

Go ahead and extract it into a private method of it's own.

I have a minor concern about that snippet though. You ask the user to "n" to quit, but in reality, anything but "y" will exit the program. I'd consider that to be a bug.

> ```
>     Console.WriteLine("Your number is invalid. Would you like to try again? (y)");
>     Console.WriteLine("Or would you like to quit? (n)");
> ```

Comment: Thank you SO Much. This stackexchange page is SO much better and has a nicer community when compared to others. Thanks again. I am just wondering, is it ok if I make a bunch of methods to do this? Or is that excessive methods?

Comment: You're welcome. You'll have to pardon me though. A "bunch of methods" to do what @AhkamNihardeen?

Comment: What I mean is if instead of doing a long code in Main(), should I make a bunch of methods that specificallly do different things?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely. You've already done this to a point. Your `Main` method is actually only 2 lines.  =;)-

Comment: IKR ;) So Long Main.

Answer (score 5):

For getting numeric values from the user, I usually create a helper function, something like:

```
static int GetBoundedIntFromUser(string prompt, int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    if (minValue >= maxValue) throw new ArgumentException("minValue must be less than maxValue");

    int input;

    while (true)
    {
        if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt);
        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input)
            && input >= minValue && input <= maxValue)
            break;
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, {0} is not a valid number between {1} and {2}.",
            input, minValue, maxValue);
    }

    return input;
}
```

Also, it looks like you're creating a new `Random()` for each new game, which isn't necessary. Instead, consider declaring a Random with 'global' scope, and initialize it only once per session:

```
class RandomNumberGame
{
    static Random rnd;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        rnd = new Random();
        PlayRandomNumberGame();
    }

    // Other methods here ...
}
```

You could also simplify your game code (and remove spaghetti-like code where many of your methods are calling each other) by using some `do` loops in your main game method. For example, you can use an outer loop that runs each time the player wants to play another game, and an inner one that runs each time the get an incorrect answer:

```
static void PlayRandomNumberGame()
{
    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        var randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 11);
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Random Number game!");
        Console.WriteLine("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 10. What do you think it is?");
        int userInput;

        do
        {
            userInput = GetBoundedIntFromUser("(Enter a number from 1 to 10): ", 1, 10);
        } while (!CheckForWiner(userInput, randomNumber));

    } while (PlayAnother());
}
```

Of course, this would requires that the `CheckForWinner` and `PlayAnother` methods return a Boolean:

```
static bool CheckForWinner(int userEntry, int actualNumber)
{
    if (userEntry == actualNumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Great job, You guessed it!");
        return true;
    }

    Console.WriteLine((userEntry > actualNumber)
        ? "Sorry, {0} is bigger than the one I'm thinking of."
        : "Sorry, {0} is smaller than the one I'm thinking of.", userEntry);

    return false;
}

static bool PlayAnother()
{
    Console.Write("Would you like to play again (y/n)? ");
    var input = Console.ReadKey();

    return (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Y);
}
```

Comment: when loading a new game, it does the Random() code again. I also put a failsafe in it accidnetly gets the wrong code again, in the `while` tag.

Comment: @Ahkam the point is that you don't need a `new Random()` **instance** every time you need `random.Next()` **method call result**. And you don't need two **instances** to implement that "fail-safe" either.

Comment: Then how would you do it?

Comment: This answer shows how you can reuse the same `Random` object to generate all numbers.

Comment: Oh, sure @Mat'sMug. On to it now :)